# How to programmatically update the alignment of invisible controls in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, animation, alignment, panel

I'm creating a panel in memory to appear in a form with an animation using the "animatewindow" method. It should appear lined up at the top or bottom.
Using the following code, the panel appears in a default position as animation, and then is aligned.

```
var
  zp: TPanel;
begin
  zp:= TPanel.Create(self);
  zp.Visible := False;
  zp.Parent := Self;

  zp.Color := clred;

  zp.Height := 32;
  zp.Align := alBottom;

  //zp.Visible := True; 
  //zp.Visible := False;


  AnimateWindow(zp.Handle, 200, AW_ACTIVATE or AW_SLIDE or AW_VER_NEGATIVE);
  zp.Visible := True;
```

**I would like to know how to make it appear only after it has been aligned.**

Note: As you can see, there is an snippet commented that make the object visible for a fraction of a second and is not perceptible to the eye, but, it seems not to be correct to do so.

Comment: Maybe set the Parent last after you set the Align?

Comment: Looking at `TWinControl.AlignControls` and the internal `procedure DoAlign(AAlign: TAlign);` in Vcl.Controls it seems neccessary for controls to be visible to be aligned. That makes sense. If you have a Control with `alClient` and one with `alLeft` e.g. you would expect the client-aligned control to take up all the space when the other gets invisible, so the invisible`alLeft` control is obiously not taken into account. Can you create your panel at a time the form is not already shown and make it invisible when `Parent` and `Align` are set? Then later animate it?

Comment: _"Can you create your panel at a time the form is not already shown and make it invisible when Parent and Align are set? Then later animate it?"_
No, because it is a component for messages then it need to be created when the form is showing.

Comment: I don't see why this should be the case.

Comment: @kobik it works.

Answer (score 1):

Only visible controls get aligned. Invisible controls do not participate in alignment, so when you set `zp.Align := alBottom`, it has no effect until after the control is visible.

The `AnimateWindow` function shows the window at its current coordinates. Thus, to make the control appear at the correct location, it needs to already have the correct coordinates before you call `AnimateWindow`. You've identified an easy way to do that, which is to show and then immediately hide the control. Showing the control forces Delphi to realign the controls. However, I agree with you that that doesn't really feel like the *right* solution.

You can explicitly set the control's desired coordinates to the same coordinates it would have if it were aligned. For example:

```
zp.Left := 0;
zp.Height := 35;
zp.Top := Self.ClientHeight - zp.Height;
zp.Width := Self.ClientWidth;
```

If this control has a lot of siblings on the form, especially ones that are aligned to the *sides* of the form, then the code above might need to be more complicated. At a certain point, you might decide that the code is more complicated than you're willing to continue maintaining, and that it's better to use the "cheating" way of briefly showing and hiding the control. No one should fault you for that decision.